# Error on import CSS for react-image-gallery with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to import the CSS for the react-image-gallery package and I'm getting the error below:

**What am I doing wrong?**

Do I need a CSS pre-processor loader?

[From react-image-gallery docs:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery)

> ## SCSS
>
> ```
> @import "node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss";
> ```
>
> ## CSS
>
> ```
> @import "node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
> ```
>
> ## Webpack
>
> ```
> import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
> ```

---

As per the documentation above, I'm currently trying:

```
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
```

**My webpack.config:**

```
module: {
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
      },
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> @charset "UTF-8";
| /*!
|   Ionicons, v2.0.0
```

[image]

**The CSS file:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
  Ionicons, v2.0.0
  Created by Ben Sperry for the Ionic Framework, http://ionicons.com/
  https://twitter.com/benjsperry  https://twitter.com/ionicframework
  MIT License: https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons

  Android-style icons originally built by Google’s
  Material Design Icons: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons
  used under CC BY http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/
  Modified icons to fit ionicon’s grid from original.
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.0");
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.0#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.0") format("truetype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.0") format("woff"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.0#Ionicons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

.image-gallery-fullscreen-button::before,
.image-gallery-play-button::before,
.image-gallery-left-nav::before,
.image-gallery-right-nav::before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }

.image-gallery {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  .image-gallery.fullscreen-modal {
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5; }
    .image-gallery.fullscreen-modal .image-gallery-content {
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%); }

.image-gallery-content {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 0; }
  .image-gallery-content.fullscreen {
    background: #000; }
    .image-gallery-content.fullscreen .image-gallery-slide {
      background: #000; }

.image-gallery-slide-wrapper {
  position: relative; }
  .image-gallery-slide-wrapper.left, .image-gallery-slide-wrapper.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 113px); }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-slide-wrapper.left, .image-gallery-slide-wrapper.right {
        width: calc(100% - 84px); } }
  .image-gallery-slide-wrapper.image-gallery-rtl {
    direction: rtl; }

.image-gallery-fullscreen-button,
.image-gallery-play-button,
.image-gallery-left-nav,
.image-gallery-right-nav {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4; }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button::before,
  .image-gallery-play-button::before,
  .image-gallery-left-nav::before,
  .image-gallery-right-nav::before {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: .7;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #1a1a1a;
    transition: color .2s ease-out; }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button:hover::before,
  .image-gallery-play-button:hover::before,
  .image-gallery-left-nav:hover::before,
  .image-gallery-right-nav:hover::before {
    color: #337ab7; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-fullscreen-button:hover::before,
      .image-gallery-play-button:hover::before,
      .image-gallery-left-nav:hover::before,
      .image-gallery-right-nav:hover::before {
        color: #fff; } }

.image-gallery-fullscreen-button,
.image-gallery-play-button {
  bottom: 0; }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button::before,
  .image-gallery-play-button::before {
    font-size: 2.7em;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #1a1a1a; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-fullscreen-button::before,
      .image-gallery-play-button::before {
        font-size: 2.4em; } }
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .image-gallery-fullscreen-button::before,
      .image-gallery-play-button::before {
        font-size: 2em; } }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button:hover::before,
  .image-gallery-play-button:hover::before {
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1); }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-fullscreen-button:hover::before,
      .image-gallery-play-button:hover::before {
        transform: none; } }

.image-gallery-fullscreen-button {
  right: 0; }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button::before {
    content: ""; }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button.active::before {
    content: ""; }
  .image-gallery-fullscreen-button.active:hover::before {
    transform: scale(0.9); }

.image-gallery-play-button {
  left: 0; }
  .image-gallery-play-button::before {
    content: ""; }
  .image-gallery-play-button.active::before {
    content: ""; }

.image-gallery-left-nav,
.image-gallery-right-nav {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 50px 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); }
  .image-gallery-left-nav[disabled],
  .image-gallery-right-nav[disabled] {
    cursor: disabled;
    opacity: .6;
    pointer-events: none; }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-gallery-left-nav,
    .image-gallery-right-nav {
      font-size: 3.4em;
      padding: 20px 15px; } }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .image-gallery-left-nav,
    .image-gallery-right-nav {
      font-size: 2.4em;
      padding: 0 15px; } }

.image-gallery-left-nav {
  left: 0; }
  .image-gallery-left-nav::before {
    content: ""; }

.image-gallery-right-nav {
  right: 0; }
  .image-gallery-right-nav::before {
    content: ""; }

.image-gallery-slides {
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.image-gallery-slide {
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; }
  .image-gallery-slide.center {
    position: relative; }
  .image-gallery-slide img {
    width: 100%; }
  .image-gallery-slide .image-gallery-description {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    bottom: 70px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: normal; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-slide .image-gallery-description {
        bottom: 45px;
        font-size: .8em;
        padding: 8px 15px; } }

.image-gallery-bullets {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 4; }
  .image-gallery-bullets .image-gallery-bullets-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .image-gallery-bullets .image-gallery-bullet {
    appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1a1a1a;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-bullets .image-gallery-bullet {
        margin: 0 3px;
        padding: 3px; } }
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .image-gallery-bullets .image-gallery-bullet {
        padding: 2.7px; } }
    .image-gallery-bullets .image-gallery-bullet.active {
      background: #fff; }

.image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper {
  position: relative; }
  .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.thumbnails-wrapper-rtl {
    direction: rtl; }
  .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left, .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 108px; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left, .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right {
        width: 81px; } }
    .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left .image-gallery-thumbnails, .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right .image-gallery-thumbnails {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; }
      .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left .image-gallery-thumbnails .image-gallery-thumbnail, .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right .image-gallery-thumbnails .image-gallery-thumbnail {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding: 0; }
        .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left .image-gallery-thumbnails .image-gallery-thumbnail + .image-gallery-thumbnail, .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right .image-gallery-thumbnails .image-gallery-thumbnail + .image-gallery-thumbnail {
          margin-left: 0; }
  .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left {
    margin-right: 5px; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.left {
        margin-right: 3px; } }
  .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right {
    margin-left: 5px; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-thumbnails-wrapper.right {
        margin-left: 3px; } }

.image-gallery-thumbnails {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0; }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-gallery-thumbnails {
      padding: 3px 0; } }
  .image-gallery-thumbnails .image-gallery-thumbnails-container {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform .45s ease-out;
    white-space: nowrap; }

.image-gallery-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: border .3s ease-out;
  width: 100px; }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-gallery-thumbnail {
      border: 3px solid transparent;
      width: 75px; } }
  .image-gallery-thumbnail + .image-gallery-thumbnail {
    margin-left: 2px; }
  .image-gallery-thumbnail .image-gallery-thumbnail-inner {
    position: relative; }
  .image-gallery-thumbnail img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%; }
  .image-gallery-thumbnail.active {
    border: 4px solid #337ab7; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-gallery-thumbnail.active {
        border: 3px solid #337ab7; } }

.image-gallery-thumbnail-label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  white-space: normal;
  width: 100%; }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-gallery-thumbnail-label {
      font-size: .8em;
      line-height: .8em; } }

.image-gallery-index {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 4; }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-gallery-index {
      font-size: .8em;
      padding: 5px 10px; } }
```

Comment: It seems to be an error with the `include` property on my `webpack.config` file... How is the proper way to configure the css loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on this line:
My webpack.config:

```
module: {
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), (IT WORKS WHEN YOU REMOVE THIS LINE)
        use: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
      },
```

The problem was that I was only including into the `css-loader` and `style-loader` the `src` folder. But the CSS I was trying the import was on the `node_modules` folder. So I need to include that as well. Hence, by not using the `include` condition, I'm including CSS from any folder.

Answer (score 3):

After 2 hours struggling I found a solution to my problem.

My problem was that I wanted to import immediately the package and style as it is in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery).

Like this

```js
npm install react-image-gallery
@import "~react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss";
```

However, I did not configure it from the webpack, as a result, I got the following error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss 1:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> $ig-small-screen: 768px !default;
| $ig-xsmall-screen: 480px !default;
| $ig-white: #fff !default;
 @ ./src/views/accommodation/ViewSpecificAccommodation.js 8:0-60
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Thanks, @cbdeveloper for the support.

> My solution is that I added the react-image-gallery style in `webpack.config.babel.js` configuration. I 've included the path from `node_modules`, not <del>src/assets</del>.
>
> This is the rule I added with style path.

```js
   {
     include: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss'),
     test: /\.(s[ac]ss|css)$/i,
     use: [
       'style-loader',
       'css-loader',
       'sass-loader',
     ],
   },
```

`webpack.config.babel.js`

```js
import path from 'path';
import Dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
const webpack = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
        test: /\.(s[ac]ss|css)$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {  // I 've added a new rule and I included the style path from node_modules
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss'),
        test: /\.(s[ac]ss|css)$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 4000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
    }),
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env',
      safe: true,
      systemvars: true,
      silent: true,
      defaults: false,
    }),
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
};
export default webpack;
```

**Reminder**: Just remember to install the following packages
    - style-loader,
    - css-loader,
    - sass-loader,